# how to solve non-linear simultanoues quadratic equation in R

Tags: r, equation, quadratic

I am looking for solution of the following stype of non linear simultaneous equations:

[latex] $$ p[\frac{x}{(y+x)^2} +(1-p).\frac{z}{(y+z)^2}] = \frac{1}{l} $$ [/latex]
[latex] $$ \frac{y}{(y+z)^2}= \frac{1}{h} $$ [/latex]
[latex] $$ \frac{y}{(y+z)^2}= \frac{1}{l} $$ [/latex]

where h, l >0 and p belongs to [0,1].
I need to solve for x, y, z.

I am stuck here. How to write code and solve this in R?

[image]

Comment: I converted your formula into an image. Are you sure your formula is correct?

Comment: sorry, there has been a mistake by me. I am rewrting the equations:
I am looking for solution of the following stype of non linear simultaneous equations:

[latex] $$ p[\frac{x}{(y+x)^2} ]+(1-p).\frac{z}{(y+z)^2} = \frac{1}{l} $$ [/latex]
[latex] $$ \frac{y}{(y+z)^2}= \frac{1}{h} $$ [/latex]
[latex] $$ \frac{y}{(y+z)^2}= \frac{1}{l} $$ [/latex]

where h, l >0 and p belongs to [0,1]. I need to solve for x, y, z.

I am stuck here. How to write code and solve this in R?

Comment: the first equation will be :
p.[ x/(x+y)^2] + (1-p). z/(y+z)^2= 1/l

Comment: Is the rightmost square bracket in the first equations in the correct place (equation seems asymmetrical)? The last two equations are identical except for a constant (unless `l` and `h` are identical but then one of those two equations is redundant). This leads to a singular jacobian. So your problem is not solvable.